# During runtime upgrade, I estimate gas fee by PaymentQueryInfo api, the return result value is so high， more than the normal value

Tags: runtime-upgrade, gas, transaction-fees

why cause this?

```go
result, err := client.SignedExtrinsic(
    "0x186c09cac19834761b573b238b6542257d05b1fc5a57688311345d8cdf7e488d",
    "5FjKC4iC797yUWmFJuirEWqvVA2ABy3d41ugxZfHyrHs2AYx",
    "113000000000000000000",
    "0",
)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
info, err := client.PaymentQueryInfo(result)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(info.PartialFee)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "during runtime upgrade"?

Comment: when use the system set_code   call to upgrade runtime

Answer (score 1):

The `set_code`'s weight is extremely large.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/88e2c9e3935c3951da3c6e3bdb8fb1ae74dc1258/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L400

As you can see, it uses all the weight of a block. So, you need to pay a lot of fees for that.

Comment: you means ,when network runtime is upgrading,  the transfer native token  gas fee weight = system.set_code gas w + Binance transfer ?